# Change WPF DatePicker to select a week at a time

Tags: c#, wpf, date, user-interface, datepicker

I'd like to modify the standard WPF DatePicker to allow a week selection.  It's fine if I'm returned a single DateTime as the SelectedDate, but I need the UI to select the entire week row as the mouse is hovered.

I've inherited and attached to SelectedDateChanged so that it will return the StartDayOfWeek as the SelectedDate (code below).

I've got an idea on how to highlight the entire week (using mouse events).  I'm hoping there is a simpler approach.

```
        // force selection to be for first previous start DOW
        this.SelectedDateChanged += (sender, args) => {
            var newDate = (DateTime) args.AddedItems[0];

            while (newDate.DayOfWeek != FirstDayOfWeek)
                newDate = newDate.AddDays(-1);

            SelectedDate = newDate;
        };
```

**EDIT**

I added my current solution as an answer.  Still looking for a good way to highlight a range instead of how I'm currently doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would add my current solution, which is to black out any dates that aren't of the FirstDayOfWeek and ensure that if they go out of my 10 year range that the right date gets selected anyway.

```
public class LocalizedWeekPicker : LocalizedDatePicker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An LocalizedDatePicker that disallows selecting any date that does not have the same DOW as the FirstDayOfWeek property.
    /// It does this by disabling the dates N (currently=10) years forward and backward from today as well as automatically updating the date
    /// if you choose something more than 10 years away from today.
    /// </summary>
    public LocalizedWeekPicker() : base()
    {
        this.Loaded += (s1, a1) => {
            this.IsTodayHighlighted = false;

            if (SelectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                var tempDate = new DateTime(SelectedDate.Value.Ticks);
                SelectedDate = DateTimeUtils.GetPreviousDateOnDayOfWeek(FirstDayOfWeek, tempDate);
            }

            DisableDays();

            this.SelectedDateChanged += (s2, a2) => {
                var tempDate = new DateTime(((DateTime)a2.AddedItems[0]).Ticks);
                SelectedDate = DateTimeUtils.GetPreviousDateOnDayOfWeek(FirstDayOfWeek, tempDate);
            };
        };
    }

    // goes forward and back n years and disables dates that don't have the same start DOW as the FirstDayOfWeek
    private void DisableDays()
    {
        int years = 10;

        var current = DateTimeUtils.GetPreviousDateOnDayOfWeek(FirstDayOfWeek, DateTime.Now);
        for (int weeks = 0; weeks < (52 * years); weeks++)
        {
            this.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange {Start = current.AddDays(1), End = current.AddDays(6)});
            current = current.AddDays(7);
        }

        current = DateTimeUtils.GetPreviousDateOnDayOfWeek(FirstDayOfWeek, DateTime.Now);
        for (int weeks = 0; weeks < (52 * years); weeks++)
        {
            this.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange { Start = current.AddDays(1), End = current.AddDays(6) });
            current = current.AddDays(-7);
        }
    }
}
```